How much (formal) semantics does one need to study syntax?
If one were planning studying syntax beyond a beginner level, how much formal semantics would they need?  If this is too broad a question, then what is the minimum they need?  Is a beginner course covering the basics enough?  For example, it's generally known how much mathematics or how much calculus an engineering student needs to know.  Out of interest, how much semantics does the average professional syntactician know?

None at all. My uni taught generative syntax, but not formal semantics (at least in undergrad).

If you’re going into syntax proper, e.g. island constraints, you don’t need any formal semantics.
Of course, a certain sensitivity to meaning is always useful. But it is not needed to be able to formalize it.

And there are many ways of formalising semantics that aren't "Formal Semantics" (ie, Montague Grammar). For example, the Natural Semantic Metalanguage is an almost entirely different way of taking a formal/formalising approach to semantics.

I ask because some classical references in generative syntax, e.g. Gazdar's paper on auxiliaries or Kratzer's papers on VP structure, seem have lots of logic and set theory notation.

@XCX I know many people who have published in syntax without feeling entirely comfortable with logic and set notation. They have learned bits and pieces as they came across them, but would not use them themselves. It depends on the specific subfields. The Kratzer example you mention is a relatively semantics-heavy subfield (some have called it "semantics masquerading as syntax"). The island constraints example I gave, or say, binding theory, or ellipsis, are not.

It is only the other way round: You need some amount of syntax to do formal semantics, because you need a structural description of how things combine, if you want rules of semantic composition. The choice of semantic rules that apply may depend on the kind of syntactic combination.
In formal syntax, it sometimes happens that you have to build on semantic notions. But in these cases, syntacticians introduce syntactic devices of their own, which will ultimately have a semantic interpretation, but which have a syntactic definition. An example is predication: You want to be able to indicate that the first sentence below contains an adjective as a subject predicative and the second an object predicative (because they differ in their syntactic behaviour). This is resolved by defining an index i as a syntactic object:

He(i) left her sad(i)
He left her(i) sad(i)

